# What's the shortest "safe" distance from a neutron star merger?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravitational-waves, estimation, neutron-stars, binary-stars

Take GW170817 for example, the first neutron star collision picked up by LIGO. Given how much data we got from that event, can anyone figure out what the "blast radius" is, and how far away from the collision you'd have to be to avoid deadly radiation?

Asking for a friend.